# Cordova/Phone Gap 2.5.0 create error

Tags: macos, cordova, path

I have a problem while creating a new android project for phonegap 2.5.0. I use a Mac and set the path variables correctly. But after the command

```
./create /pathtoProject/PhoneGap FirstPackage CatchMyPainPG
```

the terminal works for about a second and then i get the following error:

```
An unexpected error occurred: "$ANDROID_BIN" create project --target $TARGET --path "$PROJECT_PATH" --package $PACKAGE --activity $ACTIVITY >&/dev/null exited with 1
Deleting project...
```

What does this mean? I think i've set the correct path variables and have all the android sdk's installed.

I hope you can help me! Thanks in advance

Comment: I am having the EXACT same issue. But with PhoneGap 2.6.0 (Android, Mac OSX) Have you found an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package name should be prefixed accordingly with 3 namespace.

**Example:** *com.companyname.projectname*

**Try this:**

./create /pathtoProject/PhoneGap com.YourCompanyName.FirstPackage CatchMyPainPG

Answer (score 0):

make sure you can run the commands below from your terminal:

```
ant -version
java -version
android -h
```

Comment: I think they all work well:
    Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on June 20 2012

Fabians-MacBook-Pro:~ Fabian$ java -version
    java version "1.7.0_17"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Fabians-MacBook-Pro:~ Fabian$ android -h
    Usage:
    android [global options] action [action options]
    Global options:
    etc ...

Has anyone another idea?

Comment: on Windows we need ANDROID_HOME, ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME variables defined. Maybe you need to do the same on Mac.